# How to export meteor mongodb data to CSV or any other file format?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an application which collects Email, Phone number, Address etc. I want to get this data from meteor mongo db and export it into some kind of a file format (Maybe CSV).

I tried using mongoexport but that even didnt work.

```
mongoexport
```

Whats the command to export meteor database data into a file or is there any kind of package.

FYI: application is stored on amazon ec2 instance.

Comment: Not sure if you can do it directly from mongo console, but you might want to export directly from your app. Follow this tutorial: http://rafaelquintanilha.com/export-your-json-data-to-csv-format/

Answer (score 1):

You can still use mongoexport, you just need to point it at the meteor-internal mongodb:

```
mongoexport --port=3001
```

Just make sure meteor is running when you issue this command.

This is assuming you are running in development (using `meteor`, not a bundle), and using the default port (3000).